# Django NoReverseMatch when all others seems to work

Tags: django, url, reverse

Every other reverse url (edit, delete, etC) seems to work, in my templates, models, etc but not this one in my business app **views.py** (jump down for error):

```
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView, DeleteView, CreateView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from business.models import Country

{...}

# Delete
class CountryDeleteView(DeleteView):
model = Country
template_name_suffix = '_delete_form'
success_url = reverse('country_listview')  # commenting this out makes everything work
```

**The project urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^business/', include('business.urls')),
    )
```

**The business app urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from business.views import CountryListView, CountryDetailView
from business.views import CountryCreateView, CountryUpdateView, CountryDeleteView


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^country/$', CountryListView.as_view(), name='country_listview'),
    url(r'^country/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', CountryDetailView.as_view(), name='country_detailview'),
    url(r'^country/create/$', CountryCreateView.as_view(), name='country_createview'),
    url(r'^country/(?P<pk>\d+)/update/$', CountryUpdateView.as_view(), name='country_updateview'),
    url(r'^country/(?P<pk>\d+)/delete/$', CountryDeleteView.as_view(), name='country_deleteview'),
    )
```

I use `model_listview` instead of just `model_list` because the `ListView` generic edit view already passes `model_list` in the context by default (I haven't specified in my `ListView` subclass what I should want my context variable to be named) and it clashed with this code in template **country_list.html**:

```
<ul>
    {% for c in country_list %}
        <li>{{ c.name }}<br>
            <a href="{% url country_detailview c.pk %}">Detalii</a>
            <a href="{% url country_updateview c.pk %}">Modifica</a>
            <a href="{% url country_deleteview c.pk %}">Sterge</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

**And error:**

> NoReverseMatch at /business/country/
>
> Reverse for 'country_listview' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found.
>
> Request Method:   GET
>
> Request URL:  _removed_ip_:8000/business/country/
>
> Django Version:   1.4.3
>
> Exception Type:   NoReverseMatch
>
> Exception Value:
>
> Reverse for 'country_listview' with arguments '()' and keyword
>   arguments '{}' not found.
>
> Exception
>   Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py
>   in _reverse_with_prefix, line 396
>
> Python Executable:    /usr/bin/python
>
> Python Version:   2.7.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that the form is defined before the urls have been loaded.  Try reverse_lazy and see if that works.

Untested:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy


...

success_url = reverse_lazy('country_listview')
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! BUT, I've noticed immediately, another error regarding my other named views that couldn't be reversed because I didn't specify a prefix in my business app urls.py (which worked before, check the prefix ''  on my pasted code: that code worked if I would have commented out that one line about success_url). Should I specify a prefix to patterns() when I'm using a generic class view that I have already imported into my urls.py? If so, why?

Comment: Pretty sure prefix shouldn't be necessary.  Same error?  Can you share the code where you're calling reverse?

Comment: No, KrisF, it seems it works now. Must have been something with the development web server. It wouldn't work no matter how many times I refreshed. I thought about restarting the web server and then it started working again. Thanks!